# Directive's inner HTML interpolated value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Let's say I have this piece of code:

```
<div>{{someValue}}</div>
```

I want to came up with generic directive that would append a css class based on the interpolated value of `{{someValue}}` in the above example.

Example:

```
<div status>{{someValue}}</div>
```

would result in

```
<div class="green">OK</div>
```

when `{{someValue}}` expression would equal to `OK`.

Otherwise everything would stay untouched.

I know other ways to achieve the same result (e.g. `ngClass`) but I would really like to know whether it's possible to achieve this like described above - so based on the interpolated value of directive's inner html.

P.S.: I don't want to tie directive to the actual model - instead I would like a directive to act based on the interpolated value of the inner html. Hope I was clear enough...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use the `someValue` as an attribute value, so it can be available for the directive and make your life a lot easier.

```
<div status="{{someValue}}"></div>
```

Then, you can loop through `someValue` value inside directive's link function, and send back the appropriate status message.

Comment: I am aware of this approach.. But I am curious whether it's possible to do it like describe in the question. Thanks anyway...